# How to use ASP.Net Web API to send a list of keys and return a list of key/values?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to REST services and have been working through the examples for ASP.Net Web API.  What I would like to do is expand on this Get Method:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return new List<Product> 
        {
            new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Gizmo 1", Price = 1.99M },
            new Product() { Id = 2, Name = "Gizmo 2", Price = 2.99M },
            new Product() { Id = 3, Name = "Gizmo 3", Price = 3.99M }
        };
    } ...
```

To something where I send a list of products and all the prices are returned, in concept it would look like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(string[] ProductNames)
    {
        var pList = new List<Product>; 
        foreach (var s in ProductNames)
        {
            //Lookup price
            var LookedupPrice = //get value from a data source
            pList.Add(new Product() { Id = x, Name = s, Price = LookedUpPrice });

        }
        return pList;
    }
```

Any ideas, and what would the REST call look like?  I was thinking that I need to pass in a JSON object, but really am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With query string values, you can associate multiple values with a single field

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    protected static IList<Product> productList;
    static ValuesController()
    {
        productList = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Gizmo 1", Price = 1.99M },
            new Product() { Id = 2, Name = "Gizmo 2", Price = 2.99M },
            new Product() { Id = 3, Name = "Gizmo 3", Price = 3.99M }
        };
    }                
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get(IEnumerable<int> idList)
    {
        return productList;
    }
}
```

with the default routes, you can now make a GET request to the following endpoint

/api/values/FilterList?idList=1&idList=2

Comment: Thanks, I see what you are doing here.  I will give it a try and post my results.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: Note that in WebApi RC you need to include [FromUri] attribute in from of the idList parameter in the method signature. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934077/