# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read after deployment to prod

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi project mvc4 rc and a mvc4 rc web application deployed on a server.

Locally everything works correctly however on the server I get an error

> 2012-06-09 03:18:18,659 [23] INFO  WebApplication.Controllers.AccountController – System.InvalidOperationException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Business' from content with media type ''undefined''.
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, IEnumerable`1 formatters)
>      at WebApplication.Repository.BusinessRepository.GetByUserId(Guid userId) in C:\@Code\WebApplication\Repository\BusinessRepository.cs:line 37
>      at WebApplication.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in C:\@Code\WebApplication\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 61
>   .

My code that is trying to call the service looks like

```
 var url = ApiRestHelper.ApiUrl(ApiEndPointConstants.GetBusinessByUserId, "userId", userId.ToString());
 var service = ApiRestHelper.Get(url).Content;
 var data = service.ReadAsAsync<Business>().Result;
 HttpContext.Current.Session["BusinessInfo"] = data;
 return data;

 public static HttpResponseMessage Get(string apiMethod, string baseAddress)
    {
        var myHttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)
        };
        var get = myHttpClient.GetAsync(apiMethod);
        var x = get.Result;
        return x;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is MVC4 installed on the server you are deploying too?

Comment: Hi Jesse, Yes I have it installed

Comment: The same version of MVC4 on both server and development PC? There are some differences in the model binder that might account for this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934077/upgrading-to-mvc4-rc-no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-ty

Comment: Yes, sounds like it could be something like what Scott Hanselman blogged about here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCBetaAndRCUpgradesConfirmYourExpectationsAndVersionNumbersInProductionEnvironments.aspx  He discusses how to use the MvcDiagnostics nuget package to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message indicates that you are trying to deserialize an instance of `Business` from a message that does not specify the `Content-Type` header. In such a case Web API does not know how to deserialize the message (it doesn't know if it's xml or json, for example). Are you sure that the service that is being called on the server is returning a correctly annotated message? (you can check the value of the service.Headers.ContentType property).

Comment: I added thed MvcDaiagnostics and the same version is running on the service. @marcind I think you are onto something, I added a log to see what the value was and its showing  System.InvalidOperationException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Business' from content with media type ''undefined''.

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpClient doesnt allow me to set the media type so I a little lost where I need to apply it. I tried using the [FromUri] & [FromBody] however neither of those helped

Comment: on my localmachine I am getting application/json however the data that is returned from the prod server is text/html. Why would this happen?

Comment: Hard to say. Do you have control over the production server?