# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'InventoryItem'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

AJAX Call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Inventory',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: json,
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    statusCode: {
        201: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            viewModel.items.push(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Sent Data (`json`) / Request Payload

```
{"Id":0,"Upc":"3456789012","Quantity":"200","Category":"Vodka","TransactionType":"Audit","MetaData":"ABSOLUT 750ml"}
```

**Response Error**

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'InventoryItem' from content with media type ''undefined''."

Routed POST method

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostItem(InventoryItem item)
```

All properties in the JSON string are present in the `InventoryItem` model.

A **[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934077/upgrading-to-mvc4-rc-no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-ty)** regarding complex types suggested upgrading from Beta to RC to fix a model binding change, which I have done.

If the question isn't obvious, how do I rectify this error? If I add the the [FromUri] attribute to the Routed POST method, then the AJAX call is routed properly, but with an empty `InventoryItem`. If you need any other information, please let me know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
```

should be:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Notice the usage of `;` instead of `,` which is the correct separator between the content type and the charset. Also if you follow standard RESTful conventions your controller action should be called `Post` and not `PostItem` as you have shown:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(InventoryItem item)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, I was following the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/raw-content/tutorials/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations), and their `POST` action was `PostProduct`. However, the semi-colon did fix it! Thank you very much.

Comment: That's not the standard convention used by ASP.NET MVC 4 RC routes when you create a new project. They use `api/{controller}/{id}`. As you can see the action name is not part of the url, which means that the correct action is chosen base on the HTTP verb used to perform the request. But anyway, this is not related to your problem. Your problem stems from passing a wrong value for the Content-Type HTTP header.

Comment: So, you should typically not add anything to the action name other than their request type? Such as `Post` or `Delete` as opposed to `PostItem` or `DeleteItem`?

Comment: @Chase, precisely. The HTTP verb dictates which action will be invoked on a RESTful controller.

Comment: Also, since it was just a semi-colon issue, I understand this question may be too localized to actually help anyone. I will accept your answer, but I understand if it is flagged to be deleted.

Comment: I don't think that your question is too localized and I think it should not be deleted or closed as it can be helpful to others. Personally I have seen people doing precisely this error during code reviews multiple times :-)

Comment: u said we should put "Post" instead of anything else..so what if i have more than one post method then how to differentiate??

Comment: @NeelBhatt, in the RESTful world the POST method has a special meaning. It means that you are creating an entity. And since your API controllers should be bound to entities, having 2 Post methods on the same API controller is probably a bad design. You might consider creating another controller that will work with the other entity you are attempting to manipulate.

Comment: suppose there is a situation i want to delete user form role and i am getting user name and rolename from view and passing to controller and i made viewmodel containing these 2 things and i want to pass tht thing to my repository so i have to use postasjsonasync method coz in DeleteAsync it will not allow me to pass object...and there is already one post method is there for posting..