# webapi mediatypeformatter text/html

Tags: asp.net-web-api

using the webapi defaults I am able to send and receive JSON data. I now have a scenario where  my api controller cannot distinguish between get actions

- api/controller?ponumber=###
- controller?id=### (or api/controller/###)

to resolve this I used the ActionNameAttribute

```
[ActionName("ById")]
public Model Get(PoByIdQuery model)
{
     return repo.Get(model);
}

[ActionName("ByPoNumber")]
public Model Get(PoByNumberQuery model)
{
     return repo.Get(model);
}
```

this changes the urls to

- /controler/byponumber?ponumber=###
- /controler/byid/###

now the problem is when I retrieve the value it says no formatter is available for type text/html. How can i configure mvc4/webapi to use the json formatter for text/html requests? Or, how I can change my calling request to ask for json instead of html?

Answer (score 0):

**resolved**

First I need to add routing. by default webapi ignores the action. so I created a route that includes the action

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "ById", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

the next issue was action's argument. according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934077/upgrading-to-mvc4-rc-no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-ty). complex types are taken from the body and simple types are pulled from the query string. I can use `[FromUri]` to override this behavior and pull the po number from the querystring.

there is one side affect, which I can deal with for now. I must supply a parameter for `{id}`. so my urls look like this

- /api/controller/_/bynumber?ponumber=###